# How to save Offline Server Data in Application

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to save the data on the server like in the khta book application and after reinstalling the application, how to save that data offline in the application

Comment: So you want to have the offline data available after you reinstall the app?

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the data on the server always in sync with the data in the application, then after you reinstall the application and you log into your account you can just retrieve the data normally and have all your previous data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include an initial Firestore data set with the application, so that the user can use this right after they install the app (even if they're offline), have a look at the documentation about [data bundles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/bundles).

Data bundles allow you to [create a bundle](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/bundles#building_data_bundles_on_the_server) of Firestore documents/queries, that you can then include in the APK, and [load the bundle to Firestore's cache](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/bundles#loading_data_bundles_in_the_client) when the app is first started.

Also see the solutions guide on [serving data bundles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/serve-bundles).