# Firebase + Flutter: Installing app with assets that later can be synced with the cloud

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an education app using Flutter. My backend is Firebase Firestore.
To make it short: **I want the app to come with a pre-made database. Only if it's version is different from firestore it will update.**

---

This is my use context:

There are two types of data:

1. Things that can be updated frequently: like user progress on each course.
2. Things that should be loaded only once and are almost never updated: Assets like the image of each course, data of each type of substance.

I want to load a bunch of assets of the second type when the app is installed.  How can I make the basics go "inside" the app, and only update when needed?

For example: I have a collection of chemical substances. I want the app to be already installed with some of them. If the cloud version differs from this local, pre-installed database (it can be marked with a timestamp, "last-changed"), then the app will call Firebase, and load stuff. Is this possible?

---

I've read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681868/how-do-i-cache-firebase-data-for-offline-usage). It looks like it's not possible but it's pretty old (7y).

The easiest way I can think is to upload this to a dedicated server and download from there using custom logic. But it looks dumb and (as it looks like) I have no prior experience with backend.

***Am I fearing the Firestore readings too much and overengineering it?***

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is a perfect use-case for Firestore's data bundles feature. This allow you to [create a bundle](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/bundles#building_data_bundles_on_the_server) of Firestore documents/query results, that you can then include in the APK/API of your app, and [load the bundle to Firestore's cache](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/bundles#loading_data_bundles_in_the_client) when the app is first started.

I also recommend checking out my answer here: [How to save Offline Server Data in Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68862123/how-to-save-offline-server-data-in-application/68864024#68864024)

Comment: I'll give it a try and see what happens :). Thank you, Frank!